# What can I use as a Web API store for data static to the request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a series of Web API calls that will all have a client id as an attribute to the call - it's a multi-tenant situation. I don't mind having client id in all of my routes, but I don't want it in every call, and I definitely don't want the code to process it in every call.

Furthermore, the data needs to be accessed from a static object several layers down in the stack. I was trying to use Session state as the store for this, but it doesn't appear to be available at the stage where I need to intercept the call, i.e., the ActionFilter or MessageHandler stage. The Session object never felt like the right place for this data anyway.

So, my question - in the Web API lifecyle, is there a store I can use that is static to the request? If there is, I can intercept the call in the action filter, write to that store, and then read from it later on.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Properties` property on the `HttpRequestMessage` object to store information related to the current request.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets a set of properties for the HTTP request.
//
// Returns:
//     Returns System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>.
public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; }
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I was able to access the current request statically with this code: HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage - works end to end now.